# Pandas: How to Personalize dataframe.boxplot()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I am trying to create a boxplot of some data using Pandas' `dataframe.boxplot()`. Here is a code example:

```
import pandas as ps 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = ps.DataFrame( {'1':[2,3,4, 5,6,7, 9,10,11], 'blocks': [1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3]} )
#
boxes_col = dict(facecolor="snow", color="black", fill=True)
median_col = dict(color="black", linewidth=2)
whisk_col = dict(color="black")
cap_col = dict(color="black")
#
P = df1.boxplot(by='blocks', patch_artist=True,
           boxprops = boxes_col, medianprops = median_col,
            whiskerprops = whisk_col, capprops = cap_col,
             return_type = "dict",
               )
plt.title("")
plt.show()
```

But the result is not what it's supposed to be:

[image]

The result in text form is:

```
{'whiskers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7c06d8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd826ba8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7d82e8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7d8438>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7e3eb8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7eb048>], 'caps': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7c0c18>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7ce080>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7d8860>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7d8c88>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7eb470>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7eb898>], 'boxes': [<matplotlib.patches.PathPatch object at 0x7f0fcd7c0470>, <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch object at 0x7f0fcd7d8080>, <matplotlib.patches.PathPatch object at 0x7f0fcd7e3c50>], 'medians': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7ce4a8>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7e30f0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7ebcc0>], 'fliers': [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7ce8d0>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7e3518>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7f0fcd7f4128>], 'means': []}
```

What I want to ask is, how to get a boxplot more in the R style (white box, black lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up a variable for axes and you can modify many properties regarding the plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
P = df1.boxplot(by='blocks', patch_artist=True, ax=ax,
           boxprops = boxes_col, medianprops = median_col,
            whiskerprops = whisk_col, capprops = cap_col,
             return_type = "dict",
               )
ax.grid(False)
for patch in P[0]['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

[image: output]

Comment: The box contours shuld be black using `boxes_col` as I defined it. Or it must be set with another instance of `patch.set_edgecolor()`?

Comment: I am not sure why the `props` are not working. I think you'll have to set all the missing ones similar to the way patch facecolor is set. So for medians


`for line in P[0]['medians']:
    line.set_color('black')`

Comment: Well, this works:
`P = df1.boxplot(by='blocks', patch_artist=True,
                return_type = "dict",
               )
for patch in P[0]['boxes']:
    patch.set_facecolor('snow')
    patch.set_edgecolor('black')
for line2D in P[0]['medians']:
    line2D.set_color('black')
    line2D.set_linewidth(2)
for line2D in P[0]['whiskers']:
    line2D.set_color('black')
for line2D in P[0]['whiskers']:
    line2D.set_color('black')
for line2D in P[0]['caps']:
    line2D.set_color('black')
plt.title("")
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()`
But it's not so practical.